# ``Weak" Riemann Integrals of Banach-Valued Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

If $(X,||\cdot||_{X})$ is a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$, one can adapt the usual ``tagged partition" definition of Riemann Integrability on $[a,b]$ to give a precise meaning to what it would mean for an $X$-valued function to be Riemann Integrable. In particular, the Riemann Sums would converge strongly to an element of $X$ as the mesh size of the partitions goes to $0$.

Specifically relating to *Riemann* Integrals, I am wondering the following (assuming $X$ is infinite dim'l):

- Does the notion of ``weak" Riemann Integrability ever arise, in the sense that there exists an $x\in X$ such that $\lim_{||P||\searrow 0}x^{*}(S(f,P))=x^*(x)$ for all $x^{*}\in X^*$?
- If so, in what contexts does such a construction arise?
- Lastly, I am asking because I haven't been able to find anything related to such a construction, so if someone has written about ``weak"-Riemann Integrals in this context, does anyone know of a reference?

Comment: This looks like the [Pettis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral).

Comment: Oh - yes that seems like it exactly answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: This  is *like* the Pettis integral, but there we use Lebesgue integration.